# Union of two defaultdict in python

Tags: python, c++, unix, collections, defaultdict

I have two `defaultdict`, size of these `defaultdict` is too large. Sample of these two defaultdict are like:

```
a = {'20170101':('a','b','c','d'),'20170102':('a','b','e','g'),'20170103':('w','q','c','d'),'20170104':('m','b','n','d'),'20170105':('a','d','f','h'),'20170106':('a','s','t','i')}
b = {'20170101':('x','y','z','d'),'20170102':('w','b','e','h'),'20170103':('a','b','m','n'),'20170104':('g','a','n','u'),'20170105':('a','d','g','v'),'20170106':('u','v','t','s')}
```

I want to get the count of common elements in respective dates, I tried the following code, and its working, but now I want to optimize it with space and time perspective.

```
for key in a.viewkeys() & b.viewkeys():
    count = len(set(b[key]) & set(a[key]))
    print key,"-",count
```

data is quite high. dates may have 100 000 elements in it.

I'm new in c++, so if anyone who could help in building cpp library and integrate it with python.

Comment: A minor optimization would be to issue `set(b[key]).intersection(a[key])`. You don't need two sets for the intersection, just one set and any iterable.

Comment: Change `&` to `and`.

Comment: @srig no, that changes what the code is doing.

Comment: @timgeb, sorry I overlooked the intersection being performed.

Comment: @timgeb intersection must be doing the same internally, i think but not sure!

Comment: @ggupta that would be wasteful because to create a set you have to iterate over all elements of an iterable once. To compute the intersection with another set, you have to iterate over the remaining values in the set again. So, without looking at the source, it is highly likely that it is implemented with just one iteration over the argument to `intersection`.